# Lucene - Sorting Date as NumericField

Tags: string, lucene, lucene.net, numeric

While trying to sort datetime (long) numeric fields I always get a FormatException.

> When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the
>   date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

Adding the numeric field:

```
doc.Add(new NumericField("creationDate",  Field.Store.YES, true)
   .SetLongValue(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
```

Add sorting:

```
// boolean query    
var sortField = new SortField("creationDate", SortField.LONG, true);
var inverseSort = new Sort(sortField);
var results = searcher.Search(query, null, 100, inverseSort); // exception thrown here
```

Inspecting the index, I can verify that 'creationDate' field is storing "long" values. What could be causing this exception?

EDIT:

Query

```
var query = new BooleanQuery();
foreach (var termQuery in incomingProps.Select(p => new TermQuery(new Term(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToLowerInvariant()))
{
  query.Add(new BooleanClause(termQuery , Occur.Must));
}

return query;
```

Version: Lucene.Net 3.0.3

UPDATE:

This issue is occurring again, now with INT values. 
I downloaded Lucene.Net source code and debugged the issue.

So it's somewhere in the FieldCache, when trying to parse the value "`\b\0\0\0" to Integer, which seems a bit odd.

[image: FieldCacheException]

I'm adding these values as numeric fields:

```
doc.Add(new NumericField(VersionNum, int.MaxValue, Field.Store.YES, 
true).SetIntValue(VersionValue));
```

I get the exception when I'm supposed to get at least 1 hit back.
After inspecting the Index I see that the field's term is as following:

[image: Version Term]

And the field text is:

[image]

EDIT:

I've hardcoded an int value and added a few segments:

```
doc.Add(new Field(VersionNum, NumericUtils.IntToPrefixCoded(1), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
```

Which resulted on storing the version field as:
[image]

And still, when I try to sort I get the parsing error:

```
var sortVersion = new SortField(VersionNum, SortField.INT, true);
```

For every exception, Lucene is trying to parse " \b\0\0\0 ".
Looking at the prefixed coded stored as string, 1 would translate to " \b\0\0\0\1 " I'm guessing?

Is Lucene probably leaving some garbage behind in the FieldCache ?

Comment: can you show how "query" is created?

Comment: @AndyPook Just edited the question and added the "query". It works fine if I sort by DOC.

Comment: The date field is not included in the query, it is only used for sorting. Lets say that I only query for a custom field Id which is granted to return a set of results.

Comment: why are you using NumericUtils instead of NumericField?

Comment: I wasn't, just trying different options. I was using NumericField.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Unless you can post a failing test (like in my answer) it's going to be very hard to help

Comment: I understand Andy. I've ran a few tests and they all pass. I will try a few other things and reformulate this question. It's already a big mess. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a unit test that tries to capture what you're asking. The test passes. Can you explain what the difference with your code is? (posting a full failing test would help us understand what you're doing :-) )

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;
using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Store;

namespace SO_answers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestShopping()
        {
            var item = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"field1", "value1" },
                {"field2", "value2" },
                {"field3", "value3" }
            };

            var writer = CreateIndex();
            Add(writer, item);
            writer.Flush(true, true, true);

            var searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader());
            var result = Search(searcher, item);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);

            writer.Dispose();
        }

        private List<string> Search(IndexSearcher searcher, Dictionary<string, string> values)
        {
            var query = new BooleanQuery();
            foreach (var termQuery in values.Select(kvp => new TermQuery(new Term(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToLowerInvariant()))))
                query.Add(new BooleanClause(termQuery, Occur.MUST));

            return Search(searcher, query);
        }

        private List<string> Search(IndexSearcher searcher, Query query)
        {
            var sortField = new SortField("creationDate", SortField.LONG, true);
            var inverseSort = new Sort(sortField);
            var results = searcher.Search(query, null, 100, inverseSort); // exception thrown here


            var result = new List<string>();
            var matches = results.ScoreDocs;
            foreach (var item in matches)
            {
                var id = item.Doc;
                var doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                result.Add(doc.GetField("creationDate").StringValue);
            }
            return result;
        }

        IndexWriter CreateIndex()
        {
            var directory = new RAMDirectory();

            var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
            var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(1000));

            return writer;
        }
        void Add(IndexWriter writer, IDictionary<string, string> values)
        {
            var document = new Document();
            foreach (var kvp in values)
                document.Add(new Field(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToLowerInvariant(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new NumericField("creationDate", Field.Store.YES, true).SetLongValue(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks));

            writer.AddDocument(document);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you've always been a great help. Nevertheless, in this case I had a "forgotten" document among thousands with an incorrect date value. I'll mark your answer as accepted tho. thanks

Comment: Aloha andy, I unmarked your answer as accepted. The issue is randomly occurring and I have no idea of what's going on. However I have some new findings that could lead to the root cause.

Comment: did you discover the issue?